# Connecting without my permission

Tags: internet, privacy

When I typed

```
lsof -i
```

to see my Internet connection details among the sites and apps that I am actually using myself I noticed other ones like this:

*ec2-176-34-131-233.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:https (ESTABLISHED)*

Can somebody explain what it is? How can I disable it?

System : Ubuntu 14.04. (64-bit)

Comment: It appears to be a secure hypertext connection to a server at compute.amazonaws.com Does Amazon Web Services ring a bell? Are you perhaps storing data in the cloud via this service?

Comment: No I am worrying because I don't use a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visiting ec2-176-34-131-233.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com in a browser takes me to https://duckduckgo.com/, so presumably duckduckgo are hosting their service in AWS, and when lsof looks up the IP address associated with that connection, it gets the AWS instance's name and not the duckduckgo service name.

Comment: Yes, thanks I tried lsof -i while opening duckduckgo and closing it. The amazon service was shown when I was using Duck.